# Passing Parametervalues with GetItemParameters setting DefaultValues

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I have a custom webform to create SSRS subscriptions.  In order to determine if there is a default checkbox and whether that checkbox is checked, i sample the Parameter.DefaultValues. (if Param.DefaultValues == null then no default checkbox is created)

As I am working with cascading parameters (Dependencies) I make multiple calls to GetItemParameters, each after setting Parametervalues for dependancies.  However, i notice that when I select a value in Param A - which Param B is dependant on, populating the value into the ParameterValue array and passing to GetITemParameters is actually returning a defaultvalue[0] for Parameter A and populating this with the selected value..  This causes default value options to be displayed.

I cannot find any documentation stating this to be a feature, is anyone here expert in this area that can help me understand why this is creating DefaultValues for a parameter that has none?

There is an awful lot of code to display here so i will try to cut it down...

Param A "Branch" has no defaultvalue

Param B "Manager" has no defaultvalue, and is dependant on Param A selected value

```
SetParamValues(Parameters);  //Params do not have DefaultValues after this call
Parameters = _Rs.GetItemParameters(_ThisReportPath, null, true, _ParamDependenciesValues, null);  //Param A now has a default value = selectedValue

protected void SetParamValues(ItemParameter[] Params)
{
    foreach (ItemParameter Rp in Params)
    {
        if (Rp.Dependencies != null)
        {
            foreach (var d in Rp.Dependencies)
            {
                var MyParamValue = _ParamDependenciesValues.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == d);
                if (MyParamValue == null)
                {
                    Array.Resize(ref _ParamDependenciesValues, _ParamDependenciesValues.Count() + 1);
                    var MyNewParamValue = new ParameterValue {Name = d};
                    _ParamDependenciesValues[_ParamDependenciesValues.Length - 1] = MyNewParamValue;
                    MyParamValue = _ParamDependenciesValues.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == d);
                }

                if (_Dependencies.Contains(d))
                {
                    if (MyParamValue != null && _Dependencies[d] != null)
                        MyParamValue.Value = _Dependencies[d].ToString();  

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

_Dependencies is simply a HashTable containing keyvalue pairs

EDIT:
Still looking for an elegent solution to this issue.  I added a hacky workaround where I checked if the parameter has dependencies before creating a default checkbox.  However this is now causing issues with the @StartDate and @EndDate parameters because the @EndDate parameter is (apparently) dependent on the @StartDate - even though both default values are based on a formula (e.g. =DateAdd("d", -14, Today())).  So with my "workaround" in place i cannot select default value for @EndDate.